# How to find minimum distance using lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have two classes `Entity` and `Ship`. `Ship` is inherited from `Entity`. They have `x` and `y` as attributes which represents there position on 2D plane.

`squared_distance` function returns distance between a ship and an entity.

```
class Entity
{
    public:
    int id, x, y;

    Entity(int id, int x, int y) : id(id), x(x), y(y) {}
};

class Ship : public Entity
{
    public:
    int orientation, speed, rum;

    Ship(int id, int x, int y, int ori, int s, int r): 
        Entity(id, x, y)
    {
        orientation = ori;
        speed = s;
        rum = r;
    }
};

int squared_distance(Entity e, Ship s)
{
    return pow((e.x - s.x), 2) + pow((e.y - s.y), 2);
}
```

I need to find the nearest entity to the ship. I have an array of `Entity` named `entities`. One way to do that is:
Let `ship` is object of `Ship`.

`index` will give the index of nearest entity to the `ship`.

```
int min_distance = 10000000;
int index;
for (int i = 0; i < entities.size(); ++i)
{
    int curr_distance = squared_distance(entities[i], ship);

    if (curr_distance < min_distance)
    {
        min_distance = curr_distance;
        index = i;
    }
}
```

How to find nearest enity using lambda with `std::min_element` in algorithm library?

Comment: Sorry, std::min_element function in algorithm library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int squared_distance(const Entity& e, const Ship& s)
{
    return pow((e.x - s.x), 2) + pow((e.y - s.y), 2);
}

std::min_element(std::begin(entities), std::end(entities), [&ship](const Entity& a, const Entity& b) { return squared_distance(a, ship) < squared_distance(b, ship); });
```

Note you need to update parameters in your `squared_distance` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert this to `std::min_element` like this:

```
auto closer = [&ship](const auto &e1, const auto &e2) {
                return squared_distance(e1, ship) 
                     < squared_distance(e2, ship);
              };

auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(entities), std::end(entities), closer);
```

Note that this algorithm (like most algorithms), will return an `iterator` to the closest ship. You can get the closest ship by dereferencing this iterator:

```
auto closest_ship = *it;
```

You can also get the index of this ship (as you have in your version):

```
int i = std::distance(std::begin(entities), it);
```

As @S.M. points out in their answer, your `squared_distance` function should take its parameters by `const&`, since you don't need to make a copy of those objects in order to compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

auto it = std::min_element( std::begin( entities ), std::end( entities ),
                            [&ship]( const auto &first, const auto &second )
                            {
                                return squared_distance( first, ship ) < squared_distance( second, ship );
                            } );
```

You can define the lambda separately like for example

```
auto less_distance = [&ship]( const auto &first, const auto &second )
{
    return squared_distance( first, ship ) < squared_distance( second, ship );
};
```

Then the call of the algorithm will look like

```
auto it = std::min_element( std::begin( entities ), std::end( entities ),
                            less_distance );
```